# Regex to require space after comma in list

Tags: regex

I want to require a space after every comma in a list. I've got this, which works pretty well for my lists that have 5 to 7 digits, separated by commas. 
    `^([^,]{5,7},)*[^,][^ ]{5,7}$` 
The problem is it allows 12345,12345. I don't want that to pass. 12345, 12345 should pass. I also need just 12345 to pass, so the comma and space is not required if it's just one 5-7 digit number.

Comment: I think your regex does not allow  `12345,12345` https://regex101.com/r/6VhPLm/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your regex  does not match [`12345,12345`](https://regex101.com/r/6VhPLm/1/) because this part `([^,]{5,7},)*` will match from the start including the comma.

Then it matches not a comma `[^,]` which will match the second `1` and then it has to match not a whitespace `[^ ]{5,7}` but there are only 4 characters left to match which are `2345` and it can not match.

If the first part fails it tries to match `[^,][^ ]{5,7}` which in total matches 6-8 characters.

You might use:

```
^[^,\s]{5,7}(?:, [^,\s]{5,7})*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I9cSlC/1)

- `^` Start of the string
- `[^,\s]{5,7}` Match not a whitespace character of a comma 5 - 7 times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `, [^,\s]{5,7}` Match a comma, space and not a comma or a whitespace character 5-7 times
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of the string

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your regex, but something as simple as this should work:

```
^(?:\d{5,7}, )*\d{5,7}$
```

Or if you didn't intend to allow digit-only,

```
^(?:[^, ]{5,7}, )*[^, ]{5,7}$
```

Comment: @Drop04 You can click the grey tick beside this answer to mark it as "accepted" if you think it's helpful.